# Is there a way to use PostSharp without installing the package

Tags: visual-studio, aop

I would like to automate the deployment of Postsharp that's why I would like to have a text file that would preserve the necessary deployment settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is a solution although not very elegant. The instalation folder was copied to the repository and there was added an post-build action in project settings that would run Postsharp.exe with necessary parameters from the location that is in repository.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think so. We use it at business and we all need to install package.